# Replace with icon on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show an `icon` when `hover` over. 
The number `100` should disappear and instead shows the `icon` with new background color being `red`. Possible to do?

```css
.bbb {
 text-align: center;
 color: green;
 background-color: black;
}

.bbb:hover {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="aaa">
  <span class="bbb">100
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: if am not wrong, i have edited some code, try with my code

Comment: try my answer now.

Comment: i have explained with fiddle, still downvote @raulbaros

Comment: @GaneshPutta - I didnt downvote.

Comment: its okay, May be the one who downvoted has no sense

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this. You apply `font-size:0` to hide text and use `min-width` to keep the same size of container :

```css
.aaa i{
  display:none;
  
}
.bbb {
 text-align: center;
 color: green;
 min-width:40px;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color: black;
 transition:0.5s;
}


.aaa:hover .bbb {
 background-color: red;
 font-size:0;
}
.aaa:hover i {
  display:inline;
  font-size:initial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="aaa"><span class="bbb">100<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just hide the text node without hiding the whole span, but you can fake the effect by making the font size 0 (and maybe set the opacity to 0 just to be doubly safe):

```
.bbb:hover {
 background-color: red;
 font-size: 0;
 opacity: 0;
}
.bbb:hover .fa-address-book { 
  /* not sure how you're hiding your icon initially but add the styles you need here to show your icon when the span is hovered */
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.aaa {
 text-align: center;
 color: green;
 background-color: black;
 width: max-content;
}
.aaa .bbb{
  display: block;
}
.aaa .fa{
 display : none;
}
.aaa:hover {
 background-color: red;
}
.aaa:hover .bbb .ccc {
 display: none;
}
.aaa:hover .fa{
 display : inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="aaa"><span class="bbb"><span class="ccc">100</span><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's okay to change your `HTML markup` then you could try it as below and even you need to change that, as at-present `.bbb class` which is a `parent` element for `.fa`. So here to hide that text on `hover` also effects the styling on `child` element, so overcome that you can remove `.fa` tag from `span` tag thus they align side by side individually and then you could add styling as per your plans.

```css
.aaa{
   background-color: black;
   display:inline-block;
   color: yellow;
}
.aaa > .bbb{
  transition:1s ease;
}
.aaa:hover{
  background:red;
}
.aaa:hover > .fa{
  transition:1.2s ease;
}
.aaa:hover > .bbb{
  margin-left:-24px;
  opacity:0;
}
.aaa:hover > .fa{
  padding:0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="aaa"><span class="bbb">100</span><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bbb {
 text-align: center;
 color: green;
 background-color: black;
}
.aaa:hover .hide{displaY:none}
.aaa:hover i:before{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="aaa"><span class="hide">100</span><span class="bbb"><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span> 
</div>
```

Try seperating the text and icon in different span and add hover to parent element the above code will explain you the rest

Answer (score 0):

you want to disappear 100 and show icon, with some animation here you are :

```
 .aaa {
        background-color: black;
        display: inline-block;
        color: yellow;
        transition: 1s ease;
    }
    .aaa>.bbb { transition: 1s ease;}
    .aaa>.fa {
        opacity: 0;
        padding-right: 10px;
        transition: 1.2s ease;
    }
    .aaa:hover {
        background: red;
        transition: 1s ease;
    }
    .aaa:hover>.bbb {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 1s ease;
    }
    .aaa:hover>.fa {
        padding-right: 10px;
        opacity: 100;
        transition: 1.2s ease;
    }
```

html is same as your code .

Answer (score -2):

on main div hover you can show/hide child elements

```css
.bbb {
 text-align: center;
 color: green;
 background-color: black;
}
.aaa {
 text-align: center;
 color: green;
 background-color: black;
 width:50px;
}
.img-span{
  display:none;
}
.aaa:hover{
 background-color: red;
}
.aaa:hover .img-span{
 display:block;
}
.aaa:hover .bbb {
display:none;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="aaa"><span class="bbb">100</span><span class="img-span"> <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> 

</div>
```

Comment: i dont know how my answer is wrong, i got negative marks

Comment: is this okay @Hash

Comment: i didnt down vote. just saying that you should explain what you have added / changed to solve the problem.